# PHP regex groups captures

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regex:

```
\[([^ -\]]+)( - ([^ -\]]+))+\]
```

This match the following successfully:

```
[abc - def - ghi - jkl]
```

BUT the match is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => [abc - def - ghi - jkl]
    [1] => abc
    [2] =>  - jkl
    [3] => jkl
)
```

What I need is something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => [abc - def - ghi - jkl]
    [1] => abc
    [2] =>  - def
    [3] => def
    [4] =>  - ghi
    [5] => ghi
    [6] =>  - jkl
    [7] => jkl
)
```

I'm able to do that in C# looking at the groups "captures". How can I do that in PHP?

Comment: You realize that the `-` in the character class specifies a _range_, and your expression `' -\]'` means any character from `\x20` to `\x5D`. Thus `[^ -\]]` is the same thing as `[^ !"#$%&'()*+,\-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\\]]`. You need to escape the dash!

Comment: Can you show us the regex syntax you would use in C# for this task?  From [glancing at the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30wbz966.aspx), the syntax looks pretty much identical to that of the [PCRE](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) engine PHP uses.  If you had trouble, it'd be interesting dissecting the differences.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is not the job for the regexp. Match against `\[([^\]]*)\]`, then `explode` the first capture by the `" - "`.

```
<?php                                                                       
  $str = "[abc - def - ghi - jkl]";
  preg_match('/\[([^\]]*)\]/', $str, $re);
  $strs = explode(' - ', $re[1]);
  print_r($strs);
?>
```

Comment: Yeah you are right, not sure why I was complicating the thing so much. Still I would like to know if this can be done in PHP like in C# (where there is like "groups captures")

Comment: **Warning: This function was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.3.0, and REMOVED in PHP 7.0.0.** [link](http://php.adamharvey.name/manual/en/function.split.php). Alternatives to this function include: **preg_split(), explode(), str_split()

Answer (score 12):

Assuming the tokens in your sample string never contain spaces, and are alphanumeric:

```
<?php
    $pattern = "/([\w|\d])+/";
    $string = "[abc - 123 - def - 456 - ghi - 789 - jkl]";
    preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
    print_r($matches[0]);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => abc
    [1] => 123
    [2] => def
    [3] => 456
    [4] => ghi
    [5] => 789
    [6] => jkl
)
```

Comment: Yeah, this works too, thanks. But I'm looking to match and replace on a string like this "[a - b - c] [a] [a - b - f]". So [a] doesn't get replaced but the others do. I solved the issue with preg_replace_callback. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @carlosdubusm: You should edit your question to include the **actual** string you're matching against. Otherwise, the answers you get may not work for you. :)

Answer (score 9):

SPL [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) will return regex groups starting on index 1 of the `$matches` variable. If you want to get only the second group you can use `$matches[2]` for example.

Syntax:

```
$matches = array(); 
preg_match_all(\
    '/(He)\w+ (\w+)/', 
    "Hello world\n Hello Sunshine", 
    $matches
); 
var_dump($matches);
```

Result:

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(11) "Hello world"
    [1] =>
    string(14) "Hello Sunshine"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(2) "He"
    [1] =>
    string(2) "He"
  }
  [2] =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(5) "world"
    [1] =>
    string(8) "Sunshine"
  }
}
```

---

P.S. This answer is posted for the context of the question title after being directed here by a Google search. This was the information I was interested in when searching for this topic.

Answer (score 6):

To group your matches, use parenthesize. EG:

```
$string = 'bob';
preg_match('/bob/', $string, $matches);
```

`$matches` will be `['bob']`

```
preg_match('/(b)(o)(b)/', $string, $matches);
```

`$matches` will be `['bob','b','o','b']`

Comment: your $matches will actually be `['bob', 'b', 'o', 'b']`