# PHP convert <img> tag to amp img

Tags: php, amp-html

I have some text field in MySQL table that contains some HTML and image (as html tag)

I need to output the same content inside an AMP page but amp omg tag is different, how can i convert my tag to amp tag?

should i search my variable for image tag?

Comment: In a real-world examle you will have more to deal with than just the `<img>` tag. I've build a library for this https://github.com/paulredmond/html-to-amp and there is also this one too https://github.com/Lullabot/amp-library

Answer (score 3):

Something as simple as this should work:

```
            <?php
                    $string = 'some string containing evil <img src="abc.gif"> tags here and also here: <img src="xyz.png">';
                    $pattern = '/<img/i';
                    $replacement = '<amp-img';
                    preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
            ?>
```

Without seeing the actual code it's hard to see exactly what you need to do, but these links should point you in the right direction for getting stuck into regular expressions, which you are clearly going to need if, as you say in the comments below, you need to break up the old img tags into component parts and refactor them in various ways. 
[PHP regex groups captures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642836/php-regex-groups-captures)
http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html
Don't be tempted to use substrings as an easy way out, regular expressions are well worth the time invested.

Comment: Dang! You were faster by mere milliseconds... ;-)

Comment: Bad luck comrade, it happens!

Comment: is not just the starting tag, AMP img to be valid need image size and closing tag  and looks like this: <amp-img src="img/myimg.jpg" layout="responsive" width="360"            height="216" placeholder ></amp-img>

Comment: OK gimme a sec. In that case you will need to do a capturing regular expression. Do you know regular expressions at all?

Comment: i was thinking about DOMDocument but not sure is the best way

Comment: DOMDocument for regular expressions with JavaScript? That's an OK way of doing things. Post examples of the img tags you need to convert.

Comment: this answer although correct is useless, as the amp page will contains errors, this topic is useful:

    https://gist.github.com/adactio/73f404568bf5e0d000a6

replace img, audio, and video elements with amp custom elements

Comment: Looking at the question and my answer 15 months later, I agree that my suggested approach is far from ideal. But until someone posts a better answer, it stands. The link you posted looks worth following up for anyone seeking an answer to the problem,

Comment: @Ashraf The solution in your comment works very well. Thanks.