# Remove surrounding script tags from a string[PHP]

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace

Let's say I have a string like this in PHP:

```
'<script type="text/javascript">
0jiaowdnalwdnijkawd 90janolaw
</script>'
```

How would I go about stripping the surround script tags from this string? I know how to do find and replace with regex but this leaves me with a horribly inefficient regex since my regex skills are not up to par.

The only thing I need is:

```
'0jiaowdnalwdnijkawd 90janolaw'
```

I have tried using `strip_tags()` but this will is buggy and does not work like I want it to.

Comment: mmmh no `regex` no `strip_tags` there is not many left...

Comment: If website is somewhat structured I personally use and abuse string in between function. It is probably not the best solution in your case, but it is definitely the easiest thing to use when you need to get something inbetween two other things.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696412/get-substring-between-two-strings-php

Comment: How does `strip_tags` not `work like I want it to` https://eval.in/749057 isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: @chris85 I have a long string and whenever I have a less than equals operator in it it seems to cut off my string entirely. I has something to do with the `strip_tags` function because without it works fine. I have all kinds of things going on inside this string with json, etc. so it might be a weird combination of circumstances. I could not post the exact string because of private information so I quickly made an example.

Comment: Swap the sensitive data with `lorem ipsum` or `foobar`, or any generic string. We need a reproducible example to know exactly what you are working with. or if the question is specifically about the `<` and the `strip_tags` you should state that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following *regex ( using [positive lookahead / lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) )* should do it :

```
(?s)(?<=">\n).*?(?=<\/script>)
```

*see **[regex demo / explanation](https://regex101.com/r/P82KA3/2)***

**PHP** ( [demo](https://ideone.com/EVWv3U) )

```
$reg = '/(?s)(?<=">\n).*?(?=<\/script>)/';
$str = '<script type="text/javascript">
0jiaowdnalwdnijkawd 90janolaw
</script>';
preg_match_all($reg, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 2):

as follows:

```
$returnValue = preg_replace('#<script[^>]*>([^<]+)</script>#', '$1', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this `<(\w+).*>\s*(.*)\s*<\/\1>`. For the complete explanation look at this https://regex101.com/r/88NrTa/2.

The regex get two capturing groups, the first isn't usefull for you (it capture the name of the html tag) but the second capture the text between tags. So to get you're text you have to get the second capturing group (`\2` in pure regex).

If you wan't to do that in PHP, that solution looks not bad : [PHP regex groups captures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642836/php-regex-groups-captures).