# mysql - how to remove certain string from pattern?

Tags: mysql, string, replace

for example, I have a table row containing a string like this:

```
<p><img src="/assets/img/myfolder/abcdefghijkl0001_thumb.jpg"><br><br>some people can also type _thumb. if they want to <div style="background-image:url('/assets/img/myfolder/zzzzzz0002_thumb.png')"></div></p>
```

how do I remove just the "_thumb." substring inside the `<img>` and `<div>` part? I only know a little bit about `replace` command but I can't seem to make it work to only remove the "_thumb." substring inside those elements only..

Comment: Since MySQL 8.0 `REGEXP_REPLACE` can be used https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE: This is a helpful answer, but not the right one..!!**

I think, `REGEXP_REPLACE` does not offer the possibility to replace groups.So, it is better to use some high-level language; `PHP` is good, to update your database.

```
<?php
$pat1=<<<EOF
/(<img\s+src\s*=\s*[\"\'].*)(_thumb)(\.(png|jpg)[\"\']>)/imU
EOF;
$pat2=<<<EOF
/(<div\s+style\s*=\s*[\'\"].*)(_thumb)(\.(png|jpg).*[\'\"]>)/imU
EOF;
$text=<<<EOF
<p><img src="/assets/img/myfolder/abcdefghijkl0001_thumb.jpg"><br><br>some people can also type _thumb. if they want to <div style="background-image:url('/assets/img/myfolder/zzzzzz0002_thumb.png')"></div></p>
EOF;
$text=preg_replace($pat1,'$1$3',$text);
$text=preg_replace($pat2,'$1$3',$text);
echo $text;
?>
```

The output:

```
<p><img src="/assets/img/myfolder/abcdefghijkl0001.jpg"><br><br>some people can also type _thumb. if they want to <div style="background-image:url('/assets/img/myfolder/zzzzzz0002.png')"></div></p>
```

Reqular Expression Online:
https://regex101.com/r/sxY6OX/1

Comment: what does the $1 and $3 mean in the second parameter? I've been reading the `preg_replace` docs for an hour now and I can't understand how it works to remove something from the pattern.. I only see how it would add something to it

Comment: The Parentheses determine the groups;`regx=(here $1)(here $2) (here $3)` ; so I have taken only the first and the last groups; so the text `_thumb` is the second group; will be neglected.read more about : ' regex groups captures ', https://stackoverflow.com/q/5642836/992406 ; also in the Reqular Expression Online (link in Answer), you can see the groups in the right-hand side.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SET @var := '<p><img src="/assets/img/myfolder/abcdefghijkl0001_thumb.jpg"><br><br>some people can also type _thumb. if they want to <div style="background-image:url(''/assets/img/myfolder/zzzzzz0002_thumb.png'')"></div></p>';

SET @exoticstr := CHAR(0);
```

```
SELECT 'original', @var
UNION ALL
SELECT 'replaced', REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@var, '_thumb.', @exoticstr), CONCAT(' ', @exoticstr, ' '), ' _thumb. '), @exoticstr, '.');
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7a00cbac8735d96b43d1e8d692f6ee78)

You may use any char/substring as `@exoticstr` value - you must only guarantee that it is absent in column value. But I doubt that `CHAR(0)` may present in string-type column value.